# MySQL Stream- Select from multiple Tables NO Join

Tags: php, mysql

I haven't found a good solution for my Problem yet, i hope you can help.

I have a network website, where users can upload photos, comments etc. Each user and the whole page have a "Activity Stream", where the user can see whats happening on the page right now. 
The Activity Stream has the following Contents / Tables:

Photos | Comments | Groups | Bookmarks

The Tables are completely different, the only thing they have in common is a "time" column.

How do I Select from all of these tables, Limit it and order it by the time? Since i don't want to combine the data, a Join is not the right way here, or is it? I also looked into UNION, but UNION expects each Select to have the same amount of columns selected (why is that?).

Each entry should contain a type-"flag" from which table it was selected. I need the type of the content, so i could send the data to the appropriate Template. So i want a Structure like this for example (the "type" should be added with the request, if that's possible):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5501"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(19) "2014-05-22 18:26:24"
["type"]=>
    string(4) "photo"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5500"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(19) "2014-05-22 18:26:22"
["type"]=>
    string(4) "comment"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5499"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(19) "2014-05-22 18:26:21"
["type"]=>
    string(4) "bookmark"
  }
}
```

My current solution is the following:
I do a single query for each Table (photos, comments, bookmarks etc.) and merge the Results into one Array. Then i sort the Array by Date and print the results. However, i'm not so happy with this approach, since i need to slice the array (because i dont wan't to many items to be printed out) and remember the position of the slice for the "page 2" request etc. Would be 'easier' with a Single Query and Limit / Order, i guess... Another tricky part is, that the User in the Frontend can activate / deactivate the Tables which should be shown, for example, if he only want to see new "photos", he can deactivate the others...

Any ideas?

best regards!

Comment: You can use ORDER BY "datum" ASC/DESC, as per your need.

Comment: i tried it, but how do i write the query? i get the error, that the column is ambiguous. I also want a separate Array-Entry for each Table entry, my queries always melting the tables together (like joins)